# Need help SmartHotel demo pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

I imported the SmartHotel360 project from *azuredevopsdemogenerator.azurewebsites.net* and would like to build and release the project however I have certain warnings. I successfully ran the build pipeline but when I want to release it I see this warning: `The version provided for the build artifact source is invalid.` I do not know from where to take this version. There is no option in the dropdown.

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [the Azure DevOps Services Demo Generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/demo-gen/?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fdemo-gen%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fdemo-gen%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops), we can create same SmartHotel360 project as below.
[image]
And it will automatically create a build pipeline and release pipeline in SmartHotel360 project. By reviewing the generated release pipeline: **SmartHotel360_Website-Deploy**, we can see below default primary artifact: **Build - _SmartHotel_Petchecker-Web**.
[image]

Clicking this artifact we will be redirected to a build pipeline which doesn’t exist, so we need to manually delete this artifact and then re-add our own artifact, as below.
[image]

Therefore, after successfully running the build pipeline and publishing the artifacts, we can create a new release, as below.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the source alias you just need to set the Build Name, also on the version it will be automatically picked if you already have a successful build

Comment: The build name is already set by default. The version is not there. Screenshot of successful build added. I cannot see any artifcacts under the "artifacts" icon through

Comment: can you follow the steps here, may be you need to recheck the build pipeline https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops